# One index colums to multi-index

Tags: python, pandas, multi-index

I have a data frame which headers look like that:

```
Time Peter_Price, Peter_variable 1, Peter_variable 2, Maria_Price, Maria_variable 1, Maria_variable 3,John_price,...
2017 12           985685466           Street 1       12           4984984984          Street 2       
2018 10           985785466           Street 3       78           4984974184          Street 8 
2019 12           985685466           Street 1       12           4984984984          Street 2 
2020 12           985685466           Street 1       12           4984984984          Street 2 
2021 12           985685466           Street 1       12           4984984984          Street 2
```

What would be the best multi-index to compare variables by group later such as what person has the highest variable 3 or the trend of all variable 3 by people

I think that what I need is something like this but I accept other suggestions (this is my first approach with multi-index).

```
     Peter                          Maria                          John

     Price, variable 1, variable 2, Price, variable 1, variable 3, Price,...
Time
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

#### Create data

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

import itertools

people = ["Peter", "Maria"]
vars = ["Price", "variable 1", "variable 2"]
columns = ["_".join(x) for x in itertools.product(people, vars)]

df = (pd.DataFrame(np.random.rand(10, 6), columns=columns)
        .assign(time=np.arange(2012, 2022))

print(df.head())
   Peter_Price  Peter_variable 1  Peter_variable 2  Maria_Price  Maria_variable 1  Maria_variable 2  time
0     0.542336          0.201243          0.616050     0.313119          0.652847          0.928497  2012
1     0.587392          0.143169          0.594997     0.553803          0.249188          0.076633  2013
2     0.447318          0.410310          0.443391     0.947064          0.476262          0.230092  2014
3     0.285560          0.018005          0.869387     0.165836          0.399670          0.307120  2015
4     0.422084          0.414453          0.626180     0.658528          0.286265          0.404369  2016
```

#### Snippet to try

```
new_df = df.set_index("time")
new_df.columns = new_df.columns.str.split("_", expand=True)

print(new_df.head())
         Peter                           Maria
         Price variable 1 variable 2     Price variable 1 variable 2
time
2012  0.542336   0.201243   0.616050  0.313119   0.652847   0.928497
2013  0.587392   0.143169   0.594997  0.553803   0.249188   0.076633
2014  0.447318   0.410310   0.443391  0.947064   0.476262   0.230092
2015  0.285560   0.018005   0.869387  0.165836   0.399670   0.307120
2016  0.422084   0.414453   0.626180  0.658528   0.286265   0.404369
```

Then you can use the `xs` method to subselect specific variables for an individual level analysis. Subsetting to only "variable 2"

```
>>> new_df.xs("variable 2", level=1, axis=1)

         Peter     Maria
time
2012  0.616050  0.928497
2013  0.594997  0.076633
2014  0.443391  0.230092
2015  0.869387  0.307120
2016  0.626180  0.404369
2017  0.443827  0.544415
2018  0.425426  0.176707
2019  0.454269  0.414625
2020  0.863477  0.322609
2021  0.902759  0.821789
```

Example analysis: For each year, who has the higher "Price"

```
>>> new_df.xs("Price", level=1, axis=1).idxmax(axis=1)

time
2012    Peter
2013    Peter
2014    Maria
2015    Peter
2016    Maria
2017    Peter
2018    Maria
2019    Peter
2020    Maria
2021    Peter
dtype: object
```

Comment: Great. Worked! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
df=df.set_index('Time')
df.columns = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples([x.split('_') for x in df.columns])
```

Output:

```
     Peter                      Maria                      
     Price  variable1 variable2 Price   variable1 variable3
Time                                                       
2017    12  985685466  Street 1    12  4984984984  Street 2
2018    10  985785466  Street 3    78  4984974184  Street 8
2019    12  985685466  Street 1    12  4984984984  Street 2
2020    12  985685466  Street 1    12  4984984984  Street 2
2021    12  985685466  Street 1    12  4984984984  Street 2
```

Comment: First line worked but second line of code report this: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'MultiIndex'

Comment: @JorgeAlbertoPalacios `pd.MultiIndex`, not `df.MultiINdex`...

Comment: That worked as well. Thank Quang Hoang This is the second time you help me.